# What is wrong with this python3 script?

Tags: argparse, python-3.8

Have a simple python script which I am unable to make work in python3 on macOS.

```
import argparse

scriptMode = 4

my_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='Script v1.0', description='use mode as appropriate')
my_parser.add_argument('-m', dest='scriptMode', type=int, choices=range(1, 4), help='Enter mode 1 to 3',default=1)
my_parser.parse_args()

print (scriptMode)
```

Every time I run the program I get output as 4, which is the initial value I pass.this value is being used as debug as the parser wasn't working. with my understanding, the argument parser when run should store 1 in variable scriptMode and the print statement should print 1. I am running the script as *italic* python3 scriptname.py *italic*. help (python3.8.2)

Comment: `parse_args` does not modify the global variable `scriptMode`.  It returns an `args` namespace object.  `args.scriptMode` should have default value.  You may need to read the `argparse` docs some more.

Comment: what I am trying to achieve here is to set the variable scriptMode with the integer passed from the command line else default to 1.

Comment: That value is an attribute of the object produced by parse_args.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the obvious mistake. I have change the script a bit and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Changes were done to script as below.

```
import argparse

scriptMode = 4

my_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='Script v1.0', description='use mode as appropriate')
my_parser.add_argument('-m', dest='scriptMode', type=int, choices=range(1, 4), help='Enter mode 1 to 3',default=1)
p = my_parser.parse_args()

scriptMode = p.m

print (scriptMode)
```